# Java transient keyword and null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, transient

I'm using Intellij IDEA, and the follow code generates a warning: "`Expression testObj might evaluate to null but is returned by the method declared as @NotNull (at line 16)`"

```
package com.dlp;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class TestCase {
    @Nullable
    private transient Object testObj = null;

    @Nonnull
    public Object getTestObj() {
        if(testObj == null) {
            testObj = new Object();
        }

        return testObj; //Line 16
    }
}
```

This only happens if I mark testObj as transient. Removing the keyword clears the warning. Is there some interaction between transient and nullability that I'm not getting, or is this just a bug in IDEA?

Comment: The only thing( off the top of my head ) is the obvious - if a serializable instance was deserialized it would be null unless it was handled

Comment: @ jdphenix But the method already checks for that condition. While you are correct that testObj would be null if this object was deserialized, the same applies for non-transient fields default initialized to null. I have already marked the field as @Nullable. How the field becomes null should not be a concern.

Whats wierd is that IDEA thinks that testObj can be null _immediately after_ a check that it isn't.

Comment: Indeed - I suspect bug.

Comment: I think the part that is making the error has not been copied by you here. IntelliJ is referring to a method which has NotNull annotation but based on the definition of your code it can return null. Which line is line 20? That can be helpful to know. And where is the NotNull method you did not copy?

Comment: @HamedMoghaddam There was a default copyright header that I did copy which shifted everything up, and I have my IDEA set to assume all methods are Nonnull unless otherwise stated. My IDEA is also set to alias javax.annotation.Nonnull with NotNull, so that discrepancy isn't the issue. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nullability is very strict in the compiler. Yes, you do check for null, but there is a problem in that your code might be used in a multi-threaded context. Consider this scenario:

This block is executed:

```
    if(testObj == null) {
        testObj = new Object();
    }
```

The current thread is pre-empted and another thread comes along and sets `testObj` to null.  Then the original thread becomes live again and finishes execution and returns `null` for `testObj`.

The proper way to write this code to avoid the null warning is like this:

```
public Object getTestObj() {
    Object tmpObj = testObj
    if(tmpObj == null) {
        tmpObj = new Object();
        testObj = tmpObj;
    }

    return tmpObj;
}
```

In this case, you are guaranteed that the return value is never null.

Granted, this is a pretty tight corner case and most programs will never need this level of safety, but that is how compilers should be checking for null.

The fact that the null warning disappears when you add transient, seems like an IntelliJ bug. However, the suggested code above is the proper way to handle nullability for fields. If this is too onerous for you, I'd suggest avoiding adding null annotations on fields.

Comment: I think you misread my question. The warning _only_ occurs when I use the transient keyword. I am aware that threading will mess this method up, and doing something like this in a multithreaded context would need the volatile keyword or some sort of synchronization/memory barrier (I'm not entirely sure if your solution will work either, due to memory caching and java's memory model). The oddity here is that IDEA is perfectly happy _without_ the transient keyword, but starts getting upset _with_ it.

Comment: In my last paragraph, I mention that the behavior *with* the transient keyword is probably correct and the behavior without it is odd.